# Is there a faster alternative to using dblink or fdw extension to create materialized views in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, dblink, postgres-fdw

I used the dblink (into postgresql) to create materialized views from another base. However, this way is not optimal
I use it like this:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW schema.vm_nom
AS SELECT t1.colonne1, t1.colonne2 , t3.geom 

   FROM dblink('hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432 user=user dbname=dbname  password=psswrd', 
'select colonne1, colonne2, geom from schema.t1') t1(colonne1 varchar(24),  
colonne2 varchar(127), geom geometry(geometry, 2154))
```

Is there another way to do it, especially when calling columns with their type, this is very long?

I also thought of the fdw extension but I don't quite understand how it works.
I specify that in my case, I connect 2 bases in local.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to save keystroke/typing time, or execution time?

Comment: I'm trying to save typing time.

Comment: So you *do* want a postgres_fdw, but I don't know what to tell you about it.  Please read the docs on it (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html), then ask specific questions.